# Creating Sort and Partition Keys on DynamoDb

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

Getting this error when creating a table:

```
"One or more parameter values were invalid: 
Number of attributes in KeySchema does not 
exactly match number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions"
```

I followed the example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetTableOperationsExample.html)

I have my keyed attributes in both sections. The only thing I am wondering about is that my keyed attribute types are strings, not numbers. I was not able to find an answer one way or the other on that one.

**My implementation**

```
    private static void CreateTableMember()
    {
        string tableName = "Member";

        var response = client.CreateTable(new CreateTableRequest
        {
            TableName = tableName,
            AttributeDefinitions = new List<AttributeDefinition>()
            {
                new AttributeDefinition
                {
                    AttributeName = "MasterCustomerId",
                    AttributeType = "S"
                },

                new AttributeDefinition
                {
                    AttributeName = "LastName",
                    AttributeType = "S"
                },
                new AttributeDefinition
                {
                    AttributeName = "DistrictId",
                    AttributeType = "S"
                },

                new AttributeDefinition
                {
                    AttributeName = "EmailAddress",
                    AttributeType = "S"
                },

                new AttributeDefinition
                {
                    AttributeName = "FirstName",
                    AttributeType = "S"
                }
            },



            KeySchema = new List<KeySchemaElement>()
            {
              new KeySchemaElement
              {
                AttributeName = "MasterCustomerId",
                KeyType = "HASH" // Partition Key
              },
              new KeySchemaElement
              {
                AttributeName = "LastName",
                KeyType = "RANGE"  //Sort key
              }
            },
                    ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput
            {
                ReadCapacityUnits = 10,
                WriteCapacityUnits = 5
            }
        });

        WaitTillTableCreated(client, tableName, response);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify non-key attributes when creating a DynamoDB table. DynamoDB does not have a fixed schema. Instead, each data item may have a different number of attributes (aside from the mandatory key attributes).

Removing the non-keyed attributes fixed the issue